# Android Webservices with php

Tags: android, web-services, http

i want create web service with php code , PHP file containing the text and I want to show this text android textVeiw

I connection with URL via openConnection() but i have error in  class InputStreamReader

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);    
    }    

    public void onClick(View view) throws Exception {    

        URL hellofileurl = null;
        try {
            hellofileurl = new URL("http://waaddev.ahosti.net/web.php");
            HttpURLConnection myfirstconnection = (HttpURLConnection) hellofileurl.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = new InputStream(myfirstconnection.getInputStream());//i have error in this line 
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(stream);
            String hello = b.readLine();    

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Which kind of exception are you getting? Please specify a bit more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputStream class has been deprecated.

You can use:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://waaddev.ahosti.net/web.php");
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
         content.append(line + "\n");
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    String hello = content.toString();
```

Comment: why change HttpURLConnection and InputStream with  URLConnection and BufferedReader

Comment: InputStream has been depricated

Answer (score 0):

You can see my repository which is a clear example how to make a simple call to a PHP web service (with MySQL also).
In this example you have a list of product in a remote MySQL database and you get them through a PHP Web Service into your app.

You can also add an item into the DB through your app.
Hope it can solve your doubts.

The repository is:
https://github.com/alessandroargentieri/AndroidToWebService

Comment: you must download the zip file "WsMySql.zip" and unzip it on your desktop instead of classic cloning on github